# IAM security credentials error when trying to create DynamoDb table

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

I am getting the following error 
"Amazon.Runtime.AmazonServiceException: Unable to get IAM security credentials from EC2 Instance Metadata Service"
when trying to run a request to create a table for DynamoDb

Its my first time using this, and very new to AWS,  I have managed to publish an AWS Lambda function and a webHook calls it and all working fine, and in doing this I created an AWS profile so that i can publish the project

However, I'm now trying to create a table within DynamoDB, which is causing the above error :(

Its probably something simple, like I have forgotten a config  value somewhere, or haven't created the user for Dynamo or something... or maybe need to activate Dynamo on my AWS account

[image]

Any help will be very much appreciated

Thank you

Comment: ok, its 100% a permissions thing... i uploaded to Lamda and my table gets created, its just when i run local, its not creating the table, and i get the error above.... im not using the appsettings.json file for my configs, im just letting it use my "/.aws/credentials" file
Although... im not sure if it will just automaticly assume to use that file